# Debugging caja issues in google apps script [Google issue 2325]

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that worked fine last week, but no longer works today. 
I have tried to reproduce the problem in a simple example to share here but can't reproduce my problem in smaller scripts. 
The script creates a html interface (using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile) and contains an OL to which the li items are added using javascript on the client side (from an array.) 
The li items are made selecteable using jquery's $("olid").selectable() ; 
When I run this script the chrome console says

Domado: HTMLOListElement is not tamed; its specific properties/methods will not be available on <ol>. es53-taming-frame.opt.js:409
Domado: HTMLLIElement is not tamed; its specific properties/methods will not be available on <li>.

When I try to click the li items they are not selected. Instead I get the following error in the javascript console:

```
   Cannot read property nodeType_v___ of undefined 2462517803-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:39
   lk 2462517803-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:39
   applyFunction es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1696
   (anonymous function) es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1522
   fn.i___ es53-taming-frame.opt.js:96
   applyFeralFunction es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1507
   applyFeralFunction es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1535
   fn.i___ es53-taming-frame.opt.js:96
   t$_var es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1571
   Object.m___ es53-taming-frame.opt.js:404
   plugin_dispatchEvent es53-taming-frame.opt.js:1472
   fn.i___ es53-taming-frame.opt.js:96
   wrapper
```

How can I start debugging this? Can I provide the project id to someone from google to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can now be worked around by using setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
and as such disabling caja on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will come along and explain this issue. Until then you could go at google caja playground (http://caja.appspot.com/) and see if your code works with the latest version of caja. I beleive that the gas version of caja is about 3 weeks behind from the latest.